# I have two copies of the same image in different angles. I need a python code to find the angle difference between the images

Tags: python-3.x

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img1 = cv2.imread('im1.jpg',0) 
img2 = cv2.imread('im2.jpg',0) 

orb = cv2.ORB_create()

kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
matches = bf.knnMatch(des1,des2, k=2)

good = []
for m,n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.95*n.distance:
        good.append([m])

img3 = cv2.drawMatchesKnn(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,good, None,flags=2)


plt.imshow(img3),plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: please format code appropriatly by indenting with 4 spaces.